# the position of the *static* keyword in member method declaration

Tags: c++

Is there any difference between

```
class C {
    static int func();
};
```

and

```
class C {
    int static func();
};
```

I'm trying to remove the keyword *static* in someone else's code base. And I want to make sure I understand what the second example means before I do that.

[Edit] The reason to remove *static*: C was a "class" with no member variables and full of static methods. I think it's more proper to make "C" a namespace with normal functions instead of a class.

Comment: Why are you trying to remove it?

Comment: Because C was a "class" with no member variables and full of static methods. I think it's more proper to make "C" a namespace instead of a class. Am I right?

Comment: That's indeed the idiomatic C++ approach. The original coder might have been a Java developer (they don't have `namespace`).

Comment: @user2207811: You can find people that will fall both ways. Using a class forces qualification of the functions that are called, and avoids potential conflicts with unqualified functions.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas: and let's not forget that a class can be used as a template parameter, whilst a namespace cannot.

Comment: I like the "all-static" class approach, because when I design classes, I'm thinking about classes. Namespaces are just an organizational construct - I think of them as clusters of classes.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas, could you please explain what you mean by *qualification* (the *public* vs *private*)?

Comment: @user2207811: A static member function can only be called from outside of the type by *qualifying* the function name with the name of the type: `mytype::myfunction(x,y)`. Names that contain `::` are *qualified* names, as opposed to `myfunction(x,y)` which is an unqualified name.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is no difference. `static` on the function declaration applies to the function.
An `this` pointer will not be implicitly passed to this function, So you cannot access non static class members inside this function without explicitly passing the object to it.

To remove the `static` first you should know and understand the purpose that it is designed this way. Without taking that in to consideration you are just bound to create a code smell of vast proportions.

Comment: Is there any difference between `static int i` vs `int static i`?

Comment: Please see my comment under the question. I think I'm doing the right thing

Comment: @RasmiRanjanNayak: None, apart from confusing the one who will maintain it.

Comment: @user2207811: If you have a class with no data members and only `static` functions you are much better off using an [Unnamed namespace](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/lnxpcomp/v8v101/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.xlcpp8l.doc%2Flanguage%2Fref%2Funnamed_namespaces.htm)

Comment: @Alok: No, an *unnamed* namespace is a terrible solution.  A class is accessible from multiple compilation units.  So is a named namespace.

Comment: @BenVoigt: I agree Unnamed namespace is a terrible solution if OP wants to access the class from multiple compilation units if not it is the best solution. I took the liberty of assuming the former for some reason, instinct perhaps, my bad.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, in the first case, the keyword `static` comes before the type `int`, in the second, they are the other way around. However, like many things in C and C++, there is no semantic difference. So, other than "cosmetically", there is no difference.

I'm not sure why you would want to remove `static` in classes as a general rule - there is probably a good reason a member function is declared `static`.

Comment: So your answer to "Is there a difference?" is "Yes."?