# Is a class with only static methods preferable to a namespace?

Tags: c++, namespaces, static-members

I was inspired by the comments under [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16106838/the-position-of-the-static-keyword-in-member-method-declaration?noredirect=1#comment23001645_16106838).

I didn't see any reason why a *class with only static functions* would be a better design than a *namespace* (with just functions). Any list of pros and cons of these two approaches are welcomed. It would be great with some practical examples!

Comment: A class with only static member functions would be familiar to Java programmers, and would encourage them to write C++ code as if it was Java.

Comment: Isn't the preferred way in C++ to use the namespace way?

Comment: @PeteBecker what if I only make friends with C++ developers? Lol

Comment: @PeteBecker Is that a pro or a con argument? ;)

Comment: @DanielFrey it is only a pro if you really really like the sight of `new`.

Comment: @AdriC.S. Yes, some people prefer that. Their preferences don't make it better or worse than the alternative, though.

Comment: @juanchopanza what do you use `new` for here?

Comment: @GuLearn: Would you mind if I included static data members in this question, to generalize it a bit?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

One non-stylistic difference is that you can use a class as a template parameter, but you cannot use a namespace. This is sometimes used for policy classes, like [`std::char_traits`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/char_traits).

Outside of that use case, I would stick to a namespace with regular functions.

Comment: Throw in access specifiers as a difference, perhaps?

Comment: @Drew what for? In a class with only static methods, there is nothing to encapsulate, by definition.

Comment: public static methods implemented in terms of private ones that shouldn't be accessed directly.

Comment: @DrewDormann you can define whose *private* static methods in the .cpp file without declaring them in .h file in the namespace approach

Comment: @user2207811 In the (likely) case that any function is needed in only one translation unit, yes.

Answer (score 3):

Classes with static methods

- You can have class inside another class, you can't have namespace inside class (because it probably does not make any sense).
- They work with *very* ancient compilers.

Namespaces

<strike>- you can create namespace aliases</strike>

`namespace io = boost::iostreams;` Well, you can `typedef` classes, so this is moot point.

- you can import symbols to another namespaces.

  `namespace mystuff
  {
      using namespace boost;
  }`
- you can import selected symbols.

  `using std::string;`
- they can span over several files (very important advantage)
- inline namespaces (C++11)

Bottom line: namespaces are way to go in C++.

Comment: Actually, namespace inside classes make a _lot_ of sense.

Comment: It would be good to explain why "they can span over several files" is an important advantage.